# Where can I get krb5-libs & krb5-workstation ?

Tags: linux, sles

I have been searching for the following packages : krb5-libs & krb5-workstation, for  SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (i586). Unfortunately, I can't find anything. Does someone have an idea where I could get these ?

Thanks,
Eti.

Comment: Don't mix packages from other distributions, which are not meant for your distribution. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to migrate a machine from one domain to another. I have been given the instructions to do this migration, and the first instruction says I should make sure I have these packages  krb5-libs & krb5-workstation installed. I have searched for this packages for the SUSE distribution, but can't find it.

Answer (score 9):

The packages you've named are Kerberos library packages for Red Hat systems.

[image: One does not simply install Red Hat packages on SuSE.]

While both distributions use the RPM package format, the similarities end there. Generally, the packages are not compatible between them. It's a particularly bad idea to substitute core system packages from the wrong distribution, as the inevitable problems which arise (such as, in this case, no one being able to log in) will be unsupportable by either vendor.

As for your specific packages, it appears that the functionally equivalent packages on SuSE are named `krb5` and `krb5-client` respectively.

If the person who wrote those instructions is available, you should have a long chat with him.